# c++ Is 'static int' not working across multiple files?

Tags: c++, function, static, declaration

for showing you, I made a very minimalist example of my problem about 1 header and 2 .cpp files. All I do is calling `myfunc()` and this shall get a value by `cin>>`. And then main shall print the value (+3). I get the error "`a` is not defined" for the main.cpp.
I thought `static` is somehow helping here, but it's not. I don't understand what the problem is.

(I am aware, that I could write `cout << myfunc()+3;` but it's for a general purpose).

header.h:

```
#ifndef header_h
#define header_h

int myfunc();

#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    myfunc();

    std::cout << a + 3 << std::endl;
}
```

second.cpp:

```
#include"header.h"

int myfunc()
{
    static int a;
    std::cin >> a;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, it's rare that you should do things resembling what you seem to be trying to do -- if you posted a different question explaining exactly what problem you were trying to solve by writing code like this, you'll surely get advice on better ways to solve the problem.

Comment: @Hurkyl ty, I keep it mind! =) but that was rather my intention. I don't want to saok any direct solutions by others. even though I would appreciate it, I still try to solve problems on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Your `a` variable is declared inside the function (so it is local to the scope) and hence cannot be accessed outside of it. 
If you want access from main, declare it outside the scope of the function (a global variable).

```
int f() {
    int x = 23 ;
    return x ;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << f() << std::endl ;
    std::cout << x ; // Error! x is local to f() and there is no x declared globally or inside main()'s scope.
}
```

You could do something like this :

```
int a = myfunc();
std::cout << a ; // Now possible!
```

Edit: `static` variable declaration has **nothing** to do with scoping rules or accessibility. Declaring `static` merely implies a change in the life-time policy of the variable i.e. its life-time is throughout the program execution duration instead of the duration in which the instructions in the scope (in which the variable is declared) are executed. Thus declaring `static` **does not** imply that a variable can be accessed outside of its scope.

Comment: but exactly for this reason I declared `a` as `static`. I thought it keeps the value still after the function. but.. is this irrelevant for the compiler? does main.cpp itself need one declaration of `a` ? (when I put `int a` in the header.h, then it's not working either).

Comment: static does not mean access from anywhere. static means that it will exist through out the programs's lifetime **but**, it will be accessible only in the scope declared and the inner scopes contained within that scope.

Comment: ah, ty very much! that's one thing I learned then that static can't be accessed outside of the declaration scope (I thought the only thing about static is that it can't be **re-written** outside the scope. TY !). BUT, in my code `a`, (and your code `x`, you perfectly got my problem) I am not really trying to access `a`, am I? I mean, I am explicitly returning `a` to myfunc() and so to main.cpp.

Comment: (I may see my understanding problem: is it that at compile time **every** function needs a declaration of **every** variable used inside the scope? so main.cpp can't really foresee that it will get `a` from the second.cpp?!! )

Comment: wow... awkward-level 9000. of course I'm trying to directly access `a` by `cout << a+3` ... I somehow thought when I return a value by a function then it's simply known to all the following rest... stupid mistake which I try to excuse due to long days.. thank you for your patience and help... !

Answer (score 0):

"static" does two things: It creates a variable that exists once through the life time of the program, and it makes sure that the variable is accessible by name only in the one compilation unit where it is defined (so if another compilation unit by chance declares something static with the same name, there is no clash).

That means that by design you cannot access a static variable declared in second.cpp from main.cpp. That's absolutely intentional.

In addition, your variable a is declared inside a function. That means it can be only accessed inside that function. So not even code in other functions in second.cpp can access it by name. Again, fully intentional.

Apart from that, if you got around these problems (and you can), storing the result of a function in a global variable and accessing it through that variable is usually considered a very bad programming practice.

Comment: thank you!! funnily, you helped me to correct my view on `static`. BUT don't I have another problem? I mean, I am explicitly returning `a` to myfunc() and so to main.cpp. or is this equal to directly accessing `a` and so my code is not working?!

Comment: wow... awkward-level 9000. of course I'm trying to directly access `a` by `cout << a+3` ... I somehow thought when I return a value by a function then it's simply known to all the following rest... stupid mistake which I try to excuse due to long days.. thank you for your patience and help... !